# How many unique counting functions there are for strings of N bits?

Tags: algorithms, number-formats, binary

Let a counting function `inc` for inputs of `N` bits be defined as:

```
inc(b0 | b1 ... | bN) = F0(b0) | F1(b0,b1) ... | FN(b0,b1,...bN)
```

Where `FN` is a function from `N` bits to a bit, and such that the period of `inc` is `2^N`. Notice that, here, we have a special restriction: the `n`th bit of the output of `inc` must only depend on bits that come before the `n+1`th bit of the input. This is obviously the case for the traditional counting function. **How many unique `inc` functions there are for a given `N`?**

#### Example

For n = 3, there are at least two unique functions:

```
# Example 0

F(b0 | b1 | b2) 
   = not(b0)
   | xor(b0, b1) 
   | if b2 then and(b0,b1) else or(b0,b1)

Produces the usual counting: 000, 100, 010, 110, 001, 101, 011, 111, 000...

# Example 1

F(b0 | b1 | b2)
    = not b0
    | xnor(b0,b1)
    | if b2 then and(b0,b1) else or(b0,b1)

Produces the sequence: 000, 110, 011, 101, 001, 111, 010, 100, 000...
```

Comment: A useful step would be to try counting the number for $n=1$, $n=2$, $n=3$, $n=4$, $n=5$, show those numbers in the question, and try plugging into the OEIS to see if you spot anything useful?

Comment: @D.W. Ha, amazing idea. Sadly, it seems that the number is simply `2^(N-1)`. I'm trying to further investigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that a set of functions $F_0,\ldots,F_{N-1}$ satisfies the constraints, generating the sequence $x_0 = 0^N, x_1, \ldots, x_{2^{N-1}-1}$. When does a function $F_N$ satisfy the constraints?

If $F_N$ works, then it generates a sequence of the form
$$ x_0\alpha_0, \ldots, x_{2^N-1}\alpha_{2^N-1}, \\x_0\alpha_{2^N}, \ldots, x_{2^N-1} \alpha_{2^{N+1}-1}. $$
The $\alpha_i$'s are given by the following rules: $\alpha_0 = 0$, and for $0 \leq i \leq 2^N-1$,
$$
\alpha_{i+1} = F_N(x_i\alpha_i), \\
\alpha_{2^N+i+1} = F_N(x_i\alpha_{2^N+i}).
$$
In order for the period to be $2^{N+1}$, we must have $\alpha_{i+1} \neq \alpha_{2^N+i+1}$. This means that there is a function $G_N\colon \{0,1\}^{N-1} \to \{0,1\}$ such that
$$ F_N(x\alpha) = G_N(x) \oplus \alpha. $$
It follows that for $0 \leq i \leq 2^N-1$, we have
$$
\alpha_{i+1} = F_N(x_i \alpha_i) = G_N(x_i) \oplus \alpha_i, \\
\alpha_{2^N+i+1} = F_N(x_i \alpha_{2^N+i}) = G_N(x_i) \oplus \alpha_{2^N+i}.
$$
In particular, this implies that
$$
\alpha_{2^N} = G_N(x_0) \oplus \cdots \oplus G_N(x_{2^N-1}).
$$
We must have $\alpha_{2^N} = 1$ in order to have a period of $2^{N+1}$, and this gives one constraint on $G_N$.
One can check that there are no other constraints, and so the number of possibilities for $F_N$ is $2^{2^N-1}$. In total, the number of possibilities is
$$
2^{2^0-1 + \cdots + 2^N-1} = 2^{2^{N+1}-N-2}.
$$
When $N=0,1,2$, this works out to be $2^0,2^1,2^4$. The corresponding sequences are:

For $N=0$, we have one sequence, $0, 1$.

For $N=1$, we have two sequences, $00, 10, 01, 11$ and $00, 11, 01, 10$.

For $N=2$, we have 16 sequences:
$$
000, 100, 010, 110, 001, 101, 011, 111 \\
000, 100, 010, 111, 001, 101, 011, 110 \\
000, 100, 011, 110, 001, 101, 010, 111 \\
000, 100, 011, 111, 001, 101, 010, 110 \\
000, 101, 010, 110, 001, 100, 011, 111 \\
000, 101, 010, 111, 001, 100, 011, 110 \\
000, 101, 011, 110, 001, 100, 010, 111 \\
000, 101, 011, 111, 001, 100, 010, 110 \\
000, 110, 010, 100, 001, 111, 011, 101 \\
000, 110, 010, 101, 001, 111, 011, 100 \\
000, 110, 011, 100, 001, 111, 010, 101 \\
000, 110, 011, 101, 001, 111, 010, 100 \\
000, 111, 010, 100, 001, 110, 011, 101 \\
000, 111, 010, 101, 001, 110, 011, 100 \\
000, 111, 011, 100, 001, 110, 010, 101 \\
000, 111, 011, 101, 001, 110, 010, 100 
$$

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks for this explanation. Turned out to be much more than I expected.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is **wrong**, but OP asked me not to delete it.

There are $|B|^{|A|}$ different functions from set $A$ to set $B$ (every element in $A$ has $|B|$ possible elements to be mapped to).

All your functions `Fi` are maps to $B = \{0,1\}$ so we have

- $2^2$ functions for `F0` because its domain is $A = \{0,1\}$ and $|A|=2$
- $2^{2^2}$ functions for `F1` because its domain is $A = \{00,01,10,11\}$ and $|A|=4=2^2$
  $\vdots$
- $2^{2^{N+1}}$ functions for `FN` because its domain $A$ is all possible combinations of $N+1$ bits and we have $2^{N+1}$ of those.

(the argumentation is the same for every `Fi` as the argument for `FN`, I just wrote it differently at smaller $i$s for clarification)

Because every `Fi` can be chosen independently, we multiply all the combinations and get $$\prod_{i=0}^N 2^{2^{i+1}} = 2^{\sum_{i=0}^{N} 2^{i+1}} = 2^{2^{N+2}-2}$$ possible functions for `inc`.

Comment: Oh, surely there are `2^(2^(N+1))` unique definitions for `FN`, but note that `incN` must have a cycle length of `2^N` (i.e., it must be a counting function; a function like `inc(a,b,c) = a | b | c` would be excluded because it doesn't do anything and thus has a cycle length of 1). That's what complicates the matter a little bit! (Please do not delete this answer though!)

Comment: This answer is not correct.  The questions asks us to count the number of such functions that have a period of $2^n$.  This answer doesn't take that restriction into account.

Comment: Oh, I see. It was a little bit suspicious to me that the solution is this "easy". Hope someone gets it soon.